# How to use javascript in asp & c# language with Devexpress

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to use javascript in ASP.NET together with Devexpress controls. How to combine those?

For example I have .aspx page with 2 text fields like this :

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="textbox_ID" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="83px" 
        ontextchanged="IDChanged">
    <ClientSideEvents TextChanged="IDTextChanged" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>

<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="textbox_Name" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="83px">        
    </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

and I have C# source code like this :

```
protected void IDChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (textbox_ID.Text == "ABC")
    {
        textbox_Name.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        textbox_Name.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

But the page need to load to execute this function. So I want to use javascript so that the page can execute without load the page.

My Question is: if I want use this algorithm in javascript how to do that?

Comment: In short, you want to use `javascript` in your `.aspx` page, right?

Comment: This artcile explains how to use javascript with asp.net. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your Information.

Comment: Also, look into ASP.NET MVC with Web API. See https://www.asp.net/web-api. It's very good for client-side development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very easy to pass any Control Id from Code Behind to Javascript Function.
With the help of `Control'ClientId` property we can pass any control id from code-behind to Javascript function.

Suppose,we have a textbox control and button control as shown:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox_ID" runat="server" Text="ABC"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btn_get_value" runat="server" Text="Get Value" />
```

We make a Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function get_value(id)
   {    
      var Name = document.getElementById("textbox_ID").value;
          if (Name == 'ABC') 
          {
             alert("Value Match");
             return true;
          }
          else
          {
             alert("Value Not Match");
             return false;
          }

   }
</script>
```

Now,from code-behind in button click event write:

```
protected void btn_get_value_Click(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "message", "javascript:get_value('"+ textbox_ID.ClientID +"');", true);
}
```

hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call JavaScript function on textbox text changed client side event first

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="textbox_ID" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="83px"><ClientSideEvents TextChanged="function(s,e){OnTextChanged(s,e);}" />
```

Then you have to write the javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> function OnTextChanged(s,e) {  if (s.GetText() == 'ABC') { alert("Value Match"); return true; } else { alert("Value Not Match"); return false; } } </script>
```